# Inline background image added by php doesn't not showing

Tags: php, css, background-image

This is my code, 
The image shows if it a single word like `image.jpg` but it doesn't show if it two words like `image 1.jpg`. any suggestions as to wat im missing

```
style="background-image: url(Stock/uploads/<?php echo $row ["image_location"]; ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are one or more whitespaces in the image path you have to add quotation marks.

```
style="background-image: url("Stock/uploads/<?php echo $row ["image_location"]; ?>");
```